# GPS application with downloadable Maps

Tags: gis, esri

I am looking for a map application with the following:

- Windows based.
- City/Town street maps are downloaded to computer (i.e. does not required a wireless internet connection to get the map images real-time).
- Uses GPS on the computer via comport.
- Allows me to visually track where I am on the map as I drive around.

We actually have written our own GPS application which uses ESRI shapefiles.   Periodically we get complaints from customers saying the GPS is significantly "delayed" (i.e. the icon showing current location is 2-3 blocks behind the true location).

To help isolate whether it might be hardware related or our software, I would like to test alternative applications to see if they have the same delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally used [Microsoft Streets and Trips](http://www.microsoft.com/streets/en-us/default.aspx) on a couple of road trips. The mid-level package even comes with a GPS receiver.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want tracking, then there are many applications, such as deLorme, and Microsoft's Street and Trips. S&T's big brother, MapPoint allows a programming interface, which could allow you to test various things.

None of the consumer products will support ESRI formats, although the business-oriented MapPoint can import Shapefiles using a third party add-in (yes I sell one, but there are others).

MapPoint and Streets&Trips both come with road data on DVD. The road data cannot be changed with a download.